# A single or double word that describes a group of casual but important guides or scouts

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

The word needs to describe group of people that you choose to influence you. It would be nice if the word was reasonably simple or hip as well.

examples:  guides, advisors, council, brain trust, concierge, sphere, tribe

Comment: "Mentors" might work.

Comment: Why do the words in your list not suffice for your purposes?

Comment: Welcome to [english.se]. This question is not constructive: it is generating a long list of equally valid answers; plus, the OP has left it unclear what makes a "good" or "bad" answer to the question. This is why we generally discourage word requests except when extremely interesting to experts.

Answer (score 0):

*Inner circle* is a term often used for official high-ranking or at least 'influential' groups; it is used whimsically for other close-knit groups. There are other related offerings at http://www.thefreedictionary.com/inner+circle . Though *mafia* - 'any tightly knit group of trusted associates' - might be better avoided - and uses 'trusted' in a local sense.

Answer (score 0):

[*person to look up to*](http://thesaurus.com/browse/person+to+look+up+to)

*[ideal](http://www.encyclopedia.com/topic/ideal.aspx)*  n. a person or thing regarded as perfect: you're my ideal of how a man should be. a standard of perfection; a principle to be aimed at: tolerance and freedom, the liberal ideals.

*[beau ideal](http://www.hyperdictionary.com/dictionary/beau+ideal) pl.***beau ideals*** pr.* bowI'deeul  [n] an ideal instance; a perfect embodiment of a concept

> [The Vigilantes Get Ready to Pounce; Entitlement Trumps Opportunity as the...](http://www.questia.com/library/1G1-133840108/the-vigilantes-get-ready-to-pounce-entitlement-tr)
>   **Newspaper article from: The Washington Times (Washington, DC)** ...that the only reasonable replacement for Justice O'Connor is her clone. Entitlement has replaced opportunity as our **beau ideal**, and some of us have come to think of the Supreme Court as a collection of ordained seats: a Jewish seat, a black... (http://www.encyclopedia.com/doc/1O27-beauideal.html)

*[idol](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/idol) noun* (2) a person or thing that is greatly admired, loved, or revered: movie idol Robert Redford

*[role model](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/role+model?q=role%20model) noun* a person looked to by others as an example to be imitated.

Comment: Note that *beau idéal* means the ideal beauty, not a good idea. And I don’t think it applies here. OED citations: “1820 Irving Sketch-Bk., John Bull (D.) - Wonderfully captivated with the *beau idéal* which they have formed of John Bull.”; “1854 H. Miller Sch. & Schm. xxii. 231 - The Highlanders came to regard him as the very beau-idéal of a minister.”

Comment: Lol. You fell for that one? *beau idéal* does **not** only mean ideal beauty, but also, a **beautiful ideal**. http://thesaurus.com/browse/person+to+look+up+to See usage instance.

Comment: Then it has to be *bel*, not *beau*.  Best stick to English, since French is obviously not your third language.

Answer (score 0):

Writers, musicians etc often talk about (or are asked about) their **influences**.

Answer (score -1):

### More boring:

> *advisor, coach, consultant, counselor, mentor, tutor*

### Less boring:

> *cicerone, consigliere, éminence grise, guru, kingmaker*

Comment: _cicerone, consigliere, éminence grise_  - not really English.

Answer (score -1):

You want hip? Try "posse" or "entourage."

You want hippy? Try "spirit guide."

Answer (score -1):

*Mentors* is most suitable in my opinion.

Comment: This answer has already been given.

Comment: @tchrist : No. You suggested it as one of several choices. I answered that `mentor` was the most suitable, IMO. I offered no other choices. **Different answer**.